# htaccess issue rewriting page with parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two URLS, one with categories and one with a product ID

Categories URL

`accessories/category-one/cat-two/cat-three/cat-four`

Product URL

`accessories/1234/product-name-here`

When I try and go on the product url, it goes to the categories.

```
#Accessories page
RewriteRule ^accessories/?([a-z-]+)?/?([a-z-]+)?/?([a-z-]+)?/?([a-z-]+)?/? accessories.php?cat1=$1&cat2=$2&cat3=$3&cat4=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^accessories/([0-9]+)/[a-z-]+/?$ accessories.product.php?productId=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Edit:**
I switched the rewrite rules around, printed out the GET variables and I get this now

```
Array
(
    [cat1] => 
    [cat2] => 
    [cat3] => 
    [cat4] => 
    [productId] => 24015
)
```

Staying on the categories page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to reverse your rules because first one is matching your product url (because of your optional params, it is matching `accessories/`).

Now it should look like this

```
RewriteRule ^accessories/([0-9]+)/[a-z-]+/?$ accessories.product.php?productId=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^accessories/?([a-z-]+)?/?([a-z-]+)?/?([a-z-]+)?/?([a-z-]+)?/?$ accessories.php?cat1=$1&cat2=$2&cat3=$3&cat4=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What's the url you're trying to access ?

Comment: accessories/1234/product-name-here

Comment: I meant your `real` url (i guess you're not trying with `product-name-here`)

Comment: I found an error in your code. You can try again with my edited answer